# How to add an external link to react-boostrap Navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, hyperlink

This is my simple Navbar. [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/Domiii/pen/RoBQmB?editors=0010):

```
<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1}>
        <a href="http://example.com/">
          Example
        </a>
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

That generates the following warning:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of . See App > NavItem > SafeAnchor > a > ... > a.

I understand that the warning comes from the fact that `NavItem` already generates an `<a>` element.

When looking for *`SafeAnchor` + React*, I can only find [this seemingly unrelated NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-safe-anchor).

The easiest hack-around seems to replace the `<a>` with a custom click-handling `<span>`:

```
openLink(href) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open(href);
}

...

<span onClick={this.openLink.bind(this, "http://example.com/"}>
  Sandbox
</span>
```

Not sure if there is a less hacky solution that is not overtly complex?

Comment: Not to familiar with react-bootstrap components, but can't you just do `<NavItem eventKey={1} href={"http://codepen.io/Domiii/pen/JbvLbe"}>Sandbox</NavItem>` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain The codepen is right there. You are welcome to try, and you will see that its not that trivial sadly! I would also assume that it should be nice and easy, but so far it has proven to be quite a pain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Navbar.Link` and `Navbar.Text` to add text and non-nav links to your `Navbar`.

> [**Text and Non-nav links**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars-text-link)
>
> *Loose text and links can be wraped in the convenience components: Navbar.Link and Navbar.Text*

[**-- JSFiddle Example --**](https://jsfiddle.net/t29oxedy/)

```
const { Accordion, Panel, Button, Modal, Form, FormGroup,
       FormControl, ControlLabel, Navbar, Nav, NavItem,
       NavDropdown, MenuItem, Jumbotron
      } = ReactBootstrap;

class App extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="#">Brand</a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <Navbar.Text>
          <Navbar.Link href="https://google.com" target="_blank">External Link</Navbar.Link>
        </Navbar.Text>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I already tried it out, and turns out that you can have multiple `Nav`s before and after `<Navbar.Text>` elements, so that's good. However, are there any potential pitfalls related to that? Especially the fact that it is not added to `Nav` makes me a bit nervous.

Comment: Don't think that there are any pitfalls, but taking a look at the generated HTML i noticed that the element turns out to be a `p` tag for `Navbar.Text` and an `a` for `Navbar.Link`, which makes total sense. Since `NavItem` will result in a `li` tag with an `a` as a child you can not add `Navbar.Link` directly to `Nav` component. You would end up with an `a` inside a `ul`. So i guess it was meant to compose your `Nav` components around the `Navbar.Link` components, however you like. Adding the `NavBar.Text` as a parent will ensure that the padding is correct. Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: Good stuff! Already accepted the answer :) - I now think that `<Nav>` is badly named... IMO it is not sufficiently universal to justify the universality of the name, in that you can create `NavBar`s entirely without the use of `<Nav>`! Something like `Navbar.ItemList` seems more appropriate :P